# How to remove "Sign In with Email" from Firebase Auth in objective c

Tags: objective-c, firebase-authentication, facebook-login, google-signin, firebaseui

I am using login via google and facebook and therefore I use firebase Ui authentication. I got it right but I don't want the "Sign In with Email" button in the login page. My login page is as, [image]

My code is as below,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%s","viewDidLoad");
    authUI = [FUIAuth defaultAuthUI];
    authUI.delegate = self;
    NSArray<id<FUIAuthProvider>> *providers = @[[[FUIGoogleAuth alloc] init],[[FUIFacebookAuth alloc] init]];
    authUI.providers = providers;
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"%s","viewDidAppear");
    NSLog([self isUserSignedIn] ? @"YES":@"NO");
    if([self isUserSignedIn] == false){
        [self showLoginView];
    }
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(BOOL)isUserSignedIn{
    NSLog(@"%s","isUserSignedIn");

    FIRUser *currentUser = [[FIRAuth auth] currentUser];
    NSLog(@"%@",currentUser);
    if(currentUser == NULL){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }

}
-(void)showLoginView{
    NSLog(@"%s","showLoginView");
    UINavigationController *controller = [authUI authViewController];
    if(controller){
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
- (void)authUI:(FUIAuth *)authUI didSignInWithUser:(nullable FIRUser *)user error:(nullable NSError *)error {
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@",user.email);
        NSLog(@"%@",user.displayName);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }
}
- (IBAction)signOut:(id)sender {
    NSError *signOutError;
    BOOL status = [[FIRAuth auth] signOut:&signOutError];
    if (!status) {
        NSLog(@"Error signing out: %@", signOutError);
        return;
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"SignedOut");
    }
}
```

In AppDelegate.m added,

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary *)options {
    NSString *sourceApplication = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey];
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
    return [[FUIAuth defaultAuthUI] handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
}
```

How do I remove "Sign in with email". I added only google and Facebook as providers, how come there is this additional button shown  in the login page?

Comment: Email sign-in is enabled by default. There is an open feature request to allow disabling it, so it looks like that hasn't been implemented yet. https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/230

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
FUIAuth *authUI = [FUIAuth defaultAuthUI];
authUI.signInWithEmailHidden = YES;
```

Removed the "Sign in with email" button from the view.

Comment: In Swift 4.2 it is 
`authUI.isSignInWithEmailHidden = true`